# ngIf with ng-template and async briefly shows wrong value in Angular

Tags: angular

I just want to show log-out or sign-in/up buttons depending on isAuthenticated value that is fetched from the server.

When user is logged-in after the page is reloaded I briefly see sign-in/up and then log-out  `<p>{{!(isAuthenticated$ | async)}}</p>` *true* and then *false*

I've noticed that if I delete exclamation mark `<p>{{(isAuthenticated$ | async)}}</p>` this effect disappears.

So the operation on flipping the value from true to false takes so much time that it's visible to eye?
And why am I seeing true and then false if the expression is to be evaluated first and then the result should be rendered? 
And why `[ngIfElse]="loading"` does not help ?

```
     <p>{{!(isAuthenticated$ | async)}}</p>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="!(isAuthenticated$ | async)" [ngIfElse]="loading">
        <button routerLink="/sign-up" id="sign-up-button" mat-stroked-button>sign-up</button>
        <button routerLink="/sign-in" mat-stroked-button>sign-in</button>
      </ng-template>

      <button class="likeALink" id="logOut" *ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async" mat-stroked-button (click)="logOut()">log-out</button>

      <ng-template #loading></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to your IF condition and latency in fetching the request from server. To explain the first part -

```
let c;
if(!c){alert('hi')}
```

If you try above in browser console it would show you the alert, because we are saying `IF` to be true for non-existent or FALSY value of `c`. Now coming back to your case, i suppose you can easily relate with above. Your observable does not hold any value and the `!` operator makes your condition to be true and thus you see the content of `IF` for a duration while `async` flag is fetching the value from server.

Based on what i understand, as you have an `ELSE` template as well, You can either use a variable in you component with a default `FALSE` value and use that in `ngIf`. In ngOnInit of component subscribe to the Observable and in subscription change the value of this FLAG as per your business logic. With this in place you would see ELSE template on load till the point your subscription gets value and after value IF results in FALSE.
Or you can use angular [RESOLVERS](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: I didn't realize undefined `c` would be considered as false and the condition would be satisfied. If I initialize observable in ngOnInit whatever value I will put there I'll get wrong result in the end (for ex.: I predefined my Observable with *false* - now if user is really logged-in it will show Sign-In/Up buttons which is wrong and vice versa) second later when the real value will be fetched Observable will be overwritten - and I will see valid result - this will give the same visual effect.

Comment: I wanted to replace my ng-template with an empty one with the `[ngIfElse]="loading"` while data is fetched from the server.

Comment: I think you did not get me. How are you initializing Observable? I suggested to create a new variable in component and keep it false, so on load you would see ELSE template and when value comes up, accordingly your ngIf would work up. That means instead of async flag use subscribe method in ngOnInit and in subscription assign the service result to your variable(suggested to created above)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I had to use two variables to make it work. But it works. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The thing that also made me confused was that some of the links that I used to navigate around the site where usual `<a href="">` links and they would reload the whole app. I've replaced them to buttons with `routerLink` attributes and the issue with constant showing faulty value is gone while the app is not reloaded. Now the issue stayed only if you refresh the app.

But after rewrote the code regarding to @Avij advice everything works as planed even on page refresh. I'm using simple variables (not async) in the component and first I initialize them with default values and then in ngOnInit I assign them real values from subscriptions.

Now it looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isLoggedOut">
    <button routerLink="/sign-up" id="sign-up-button" mat-stroked-button>sign-up</button>
    <button routerLink="/sign-in" mat-stroked-button>sign-in</button>
  </ng-template>

  <button class="likeALink" id="logOut" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" mat-stroked-button (click)="logOut()">log-out</button>
```

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

// initialize with default/fake values
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.isLoggedOut = false;

// initialize with true value once with a method isUserAuthenticated()
    this.authService.isUserAuthenticated().subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated) => {
        this.isLoggedIn = isAuthenticated;
        this.isLoggedOut = !isAuthenticated;
      }
    );

// subscribe to Subject<boolean> to change authentication state. The 
    Subject is triggered on Sign-In and LogOut

this.authService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated) => {
        this.isLoggedIn = isAuthenticated;
        this.isLoggedOut = !isAuthenticated;
      }
    );

 }
```

**LogOut method:**

```
  logOut() {
this.authService.isAuthenticated.next(false);
```

}

**SignIn method:**

```
signIn(){
this.authService.isAuthenticated.next(true);
}
```